# как я могу скопировать содержимое потока "streamone", который находится в цикле, в другой поток "streamtwo"?

Tags: c#

как я могу скопировать содержимое потока "streamone", который находится в цикле, в другой поток "streamtwo"?

Я попытался использовать метод "CopyTo" или "writeTo", но все они возвращают значение null

```
public static byte[] one()
{
    using var streamtwo = new MemoryStream { Position = 0 };

    foreach (string th in path.fold)
    {
        using var streamone = new MemoryStream { Position = 0 };
        {
           byte[] historys = Uls(his).ToArray();
           streamone.Write(historys, 0, historys.Length);
        }
        //streamone.CopyTo(streamtwo);
     }
    return streamtwo?.ToArray() ?? null;
}
```

Comment: а почему сразу в streamtwo не писать?